# How operands are promoted in a long expression?

Tags: c++, types, casting, promotions

If I have an expression like the following:

```
double d = floatVar / intVar;
```

`intVar` will be promoted to a `float` and then the returned `float` result will be converted to a `double` and assigned to `d`. But what happens if I have a long expression, such as:

```
double d = floatVar / intVar * shortVar + charVar + intVar2;
```

Will all of the variables be promoted to a `float`, and then the returned `float` result will be converted to a `double` and assigned to `d`?

Also if I have the following:

```
double d = (floatVar / intVar) * shortVar + charVar + intVar2;
```

Will `intVar` be converted to a `float`, while `shortVar` and `charVar` will be converted to an `int`, and then the returned `int` result from `shortVar + charVar + intVar2` will be converted to a `float` and multiplied with the returned `float` result of `(floatVar / intVar)`, and this returned `float` result will be converted to a double and assigned to `d`?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, yes, and yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order of operations applies. `/` and `*` and `+` are all left-associative, and `/` and `*` have equal precedence (which is greater than that of `+`), so this:

```
double b = floatVar / intVar * shortVar + charVar + intVar2;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
double b = (((floatVar / intVar) * shortVar) + charVar) + intVar2;
```

At each step, the appropriate conversions are performed: `intVar` is converted to `float`, `shortVar` is converted to `float`, `charVar` is converted to `float`, `intVar2` is converted to `float`. The end-result is promoted to `double`.

If, on the other hand, you were to wrap `charVar + intVar2` in parentheses to force that operation to take place first, then `charVar` would be promoted to `int` (assuming that the range of `char` fits within the range of `int`, as it does on almost any system you're likely to encounter), and the resulting sum would be converted to `float`.

Comment: "assuming that char is a signed type" What if `char` is an unsigned type, what will happen here: `(charVar + intVar2)`?

Comment: @John: Usually the same, actually. The only case where something different happens is if `char` is an unsigned type *and* its range does not fit in the range of `int`. (`int` is required to support at least the range of a sixteen-bit one's-complement value, and `char` is required to be the size of a byte, so I think this is only possible on a system where bytes have 16 or more bits. So, vanishingly rare. I'll adjust my answer to avoid implying that it's more common than it is.)